# How do I generate a new public / private keypair for iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, macos, cryptography

Creating a simple public/private keypair, such as through ssh-keygen does not create a file I can import into Keychain Access.  Does anyone know how to create a new keypair for iPhone development?

Comment: Are you trying to ssh into iphone ?

Comment: Nope, trying to create a new identity to sign iPhone apps within my company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to generate a new key pair for your Keychain Access, simply selection the action "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority...". This will generate the key pair and a CSR. Once the CSR deleted, you have your key pair. It's a little bit tricky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be a registered iPhone developer. Then, go to the portal and log in:

[iPhone Dev Portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/my/overview/index.action)

Then click on the "Certificates" link and follow the directions. A CSR will be generated, and somebody will have to approve it before your cert will be available. Then just install it into the keychain.

Comment: This requires you to send a CSR with an existing keypair.  I'm looking to create a new one.

Comment: If you will take a look at this page, you'll see that creating a new keypair is the first step in creating a CSR.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/my/certificates/howto.action

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Keychain Access for generating they keypair and cert signing request, but have been having issues on macOS 10.14.

Instead, I was able to do it successfully using Xcode [following Apple's guide here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09).

Basically you do the following:

1. Xcode Preferences -> Accounts -> Sign in with your Apple Developer Account
2. Select the Developer Team you want to use and click "Manage Certificates"
3. In the modal pop-up dialogue, click the plus button to add a new certificate and select the cert type.

Xcode should handle the rest. If you want to export a `.p12` file containing your keypair you can just right-click the cert and select "Export Certificate." Hope this helps.